# add up every array's length inside result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

so i am trying to get distinct array values in mongoose like this

```
await Model.distinct('array');
```

and my aim is to get every array and add up their lengths, it could be easily done with for loop like so

```
for(const val of array){
    sum += array.length
};
```

but I really want to not use for loop, so is there any way to implement such thing with O(1) ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in O(1) time. If you want to improve performance, you can consider using a map-reduce solution like Spark, which is highly unnecessary unless you have a huge amount of data

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate query for performing the opertaion.

```
const sum = await Model.aggregate(
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$array'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
       path: '$_id'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      total_length: { $sum: '$_id'}
    }
  }
)
```

Though the operation will not be O(1) but will be significantly faster as well as use very less memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may use native MongoDB solution (`$group` + sum array size). It's up `x2` faster than a regular `for` loop

```
await Model.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$array"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      sum: {
        $sum: {
          $size: "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XMM2PZVmo9K)